# What is the command to enable 3rd party SFP+ transceivers on Arista switch?

Tags: networking, switch, 10gbethernet, sfp

Does anyone know the command that enables the usage of 3rd party SFP+ on an Arista 7148S switch?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Login as admin;
2. Enable privileged access;
3. Go to the bash shell;
4. Touch the filename /mnt/flash/enable3px;
5. Reboot the switch.

Below is a session from EOS-4.11.6:

```
localhost login: admin
localhost>ena
localhost#bash

Arista Networks EOS shell

[admin@localhost ~]$ touch /mnt/flash/enable3px
[admin@localhost ~]$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: According to an anonymous user... `this is either false or not applicable to most arista switches. this command does not exist on the /mnt/flash directory on 7124s, and is likely a troll.`

Comment: According to a 1 rep user... `bash: /mnt/flash/enable3px: No such file or directory`

Comment: Interesting :) I'm not sure. I don't have access to Arista anymore.

Comment: Seems I can't comment yet, so this is confirming @waszkiewicz answer worked for us. We just received a new 7150s. Using the Finisar SFP+ modules we had in stock produced "errdisabled xcvr-unsupported." Using the commands above, we are now up and running. "connected a-full a-1G 1000BASE-T" EOS-4.14.1F.swi Just saw the rest of the question was for a EOL 7148S. We have a 7150S, so ymmv.

Comment: This worked for me today on an Arista 7148.  Thanks.

Comment: We come full-circle. This worked great for me on an Arista 7050S today.

Comment: Thank you, worked wonderfully for my switches. Aristo 7150S running 4.12.7.

Comment: Thank a lot, worked on my Arista 7150S running 4.19.8.

Comment: Worked on my Arista 7150S running 4.19.10M.

Comment: CONFIRMED WORKING - I am running an Arista DCS7124S and this worked for me. The Transceivers were actual Arista modules however my machine was built when the company was still called "Arastra" so the newer modules confused it to thinking they were third party. Now I have full 10G fiber!

Answer (score 4):

The enable3px file is a dummy file. You can create a 0kb txt and rename it "enable3px" and it will work all the same. Hope this helps.

This method seems to have been disabled per arista EOS 11.3

Comment: Just worked on 4.12.7 for me.