# What command enables non-Arista SFP+ in the DCS-7124s?

Tags: command-line-interface, sfp

What command enables non-Arista SFP+ in the DCS-7124s?
And how do you enter it?

Answer (score 1):

`/mnt/flash/enable3px unauthenticForcedEnabled`

See: [What is the command to enable 3rd party SFP+ transceivers on Arista switch?](https://serverfault.com/questions/281534/what-is-the-command-to-enable-3rd-party-sfp-transceivers-on-arista-switch)